# Pfaffian minors of skew symmetric matrix under perturbation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, sg.symplectic-geometry, determinants

Suppose $A$ be a skew-symmetric matrix whose entries are positive numbers. A perturbation of $A$, $A'$, is obtained by adding another skew-symmetric matrix whose entries are positive integers.

My question is for all such $A$ is there any perturbation $A'$ such that all Pfaffian minors of $A'$ are positive?

By definition a Pfaffian minor of a skew symmetric matrix $A$ is a Pfaffian of a submatrix of $A$ consisting of rows and columns indexed by $i_1, i_2, ..., i_{2t}$ for some $i_1 < i_2 < ... < i_{2t}$.

Comment: By positive you mean positive above the diagonal right? But doesn't this question just come down to "is there a matrix $B$ all of whose Pfaffians are nonnegative"? Because, if there is, we can choose $t$ large enough that $tB-A$ is positive, and then $tB$ is a perturbation of $A$ by your definition. I assume you left something out of the conditions.

Comment: I really meant for a fixed definition of pfaffian, the pfaffian (as a number) is positive for all those minors.

Comment: Okay. But your definition of perturbation is that $A'$ is a perturbation of $A$ if $A'-A$ is nonnegative, with no hypothesis that $A'-A$ be small. So, take any positive $B$ and then, for any $A$, if we take $t$ sufficiently large, $tB$ will be a perturbation of $A$. Is that what you wanted to ask for?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your question. Perturbation is done by skew symmetric matrices with positive integers entires while $A$ could be any skew symmetric matrix with positive real entries.

Comment: You write "A perturbation of A, A′, is obtained by adding another skew-symmetric matrix whose entries are positive integers". Is this the definition of perturbation? Should the definition not include a condition that $A'-A$ is small?

Comment: not really. This is not standard definition of perturbation. I am just calling this a perturbation.

Comment: Okay, I'll drop out and leave someone else to answer this. I am pretty sure the question is of the form: Given $A$ a skew symmetric matrix obeying CONDITIONS, do there exist skew symetric matrices $D$ and $A'$ obeying $A+D=A'$ and CONDITIONS? But I can't tell what those conditions are.

Comment: do you know the answer already?

Comment: No, I don't know what the question is. But its only been two hours and maybe I'm being dense and everyone else understands this.

Comment: "skew-symmetric matrix whose entries are positive integers" wut? How can two entries be positive integers if one of them is the negative of the other?

Comment: I really meant the upper diagonal entries!

Comment: So by scaling $D= A'-A$ by a large integer, the problem reduces to finding a skew-symmetric matrix with positive integer entries above the diagonal such that all Pfaffians are positive. In fact, one can ignore the integrality and allow for arbitrary nonnegative entries (which can then be approximated by rationals and zeroes replaced by small rationals).

Comment: I suppose that existence could be proved by induction on $n$; there might also be some explicit construction(s).

Comment: @LevBorisov, could you please explain "the problem reduces to finding a skew-symmetric matrix with positive integer entries above the diagonal such that all Pfaffians are positive" in a bit detail.

Comment: If you have $A' = A + t D$, then Pfaffians of $A'$ will have as their leading terms as $t\to \infty$ the Pfaffians of $D$ times the appropriate power of $t$. So positivity for $A'$ follows from that of $D$.

Comment: You can probably make $D$ with positive minors by having $D_{ij}$ grow extremely fast in the lexicographic order so that one of the terms in each Pfaffian dominates the rest of the terms.